# Why am I getting this error trying to install Subclipse from the update site?

Tags: eclipse, subclipse, failed-installation

I am trying to install Subclipse 1.6.x on Eclipse Helios (3.6) on a 64-bit Windows 7 machine. I go to `Help` -> `Install New Software...` and then enter the following update site into the dialog box: `http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.6.x`. I give it a name and click okay and it tries to connect to the repository for about 15 seconds and then the follow error dialog pops up:

[image]

To be clear, the update site that I have entered into the box is `http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.6.x` and is NOT `http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.6.x/content.xml` yet it seems to think that this is the repository being requested. I have successfully installed Subclipse 1.6.x on other similar Window's machines and have never come across this error before.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you somehow removed the '.' between '6' and 'x'
You have http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.6x
it should be
http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.6.x

Answer (score 3):

Follow the below steps

1. Click on Window in Eclipse Menu bar
2. Choose Preferences
3. Click on network Connections
4. Change the Active Provider to "Direct"

Its worked fine for me!!!